# Why can't I use induction to prove this equivalency relation between the union and intersection of these sets up to infinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I came upon this question in my math book:
[image]

Why is it that I can't use induction to prove this? I mean, it states it in the problem, that induction is for ever value in the natural numbers; but doesn't that go up to infinity? Furthermore, I cannot understand how to come up with an example as it has asked. Can someone better help me understand what the problem is meaning and what I am misunderstanding about induction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This comes up over and over again.  Induction proves that a statement $P(n)$ is true for each (finite) natural $n$,  and $n=\infty$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Good example: "$\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ is a finite set" is true for every $n$ by induction, but false for $n=\infty$.

Comment: @Randall Oooo, I love that example you gave here. That makes it a lot clearer what exactly is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Base case: $1$ is finite.  Inductive step: If $n$ is finite, $n+1$ is finite.  (...which is certainly true.)  By induction all positive integers are finite.  (... also true.)

But from this we cannot conclude that the limit cardinal of the positive integers ("infinity") is finite.  All we can conclude is that every number accessible by starting at $1$ and proceeding by $+1$s is finite.

We need a sequence of $B_i$ such that any finite collection of them has at least one point in common, but every point of $\Bbb{R}$ is outside at least one of them.  How about $B_i$ is the set of rationals (in lowest terms) with denominator greater than $i$ (where zero is $0/1$)?  Any collection of them includes all the points in the one with largest index.  No irrational point is in any $B_i$ and every rational point in lowest terms has a definite denominator, $d$ which is excluded from every $B_i$ with $i \geq d$.

Another way to go with the $B_i$: Let $B_i$ be the positive integers divisible by $i$.  The intersection of a collection of them is the $B_j$ where $j$ is the least common multiple of the indices in the collection, so is never empty.  But no integer is divisible by all integers, so the intersection of all the $B_i$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Induction can get messy with infinity. For example, consider the following claim:

For any collection of finite sets, $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, the union of them is finite.

Using induction, we could say that this is true. But this claim it is not true, as if we let $a_k = \{k\}$, then

$$\cup_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \mathbb{N}$$

Which is not finite. To elaborate more, induction only proves that some property is true for all natural numbers. This does not necessarily imply that the same statement is true for some limit to infinity.

Hope this helps!